# discord bot doesn't play music

Tags: javascript, discord

I created this code for a discord bot to play music from youtube, but no sound comes out, can anyone help me?I've seen most of the tutorials and everything. I changed several things and nothing. He joins the discord channel. Finds the music and does not play.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const { joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const { EmbedBuilder  } = require('discord.js');
const { createAudioPlayer, createAudioResource } = require('@discordjs/voice');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('tocar')
        .setDescription('Toca uma música do YouTube')
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('nome')
                .setDescription('O nome da música')
                .setRequired(true)),
    async execute(interaction) {
        // Pega o valor da opção "nome"
        const nome = interaction.options.getString('nome');

        try {
            // Obtém informações do primeiro vídeo correspondente à pesquisa
            const videoInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(nome);
            const videoID = videoInfo.videoDetails.videoId;

            // Cria uma conexão ao canal de voz do usuário
            const voiceChannel = interaction.member.voice.channel;
            if (!voiceChannel) {
                await interaction.reply('Você precisa estar em um canal de voz para usar esse comando.');
                return;
            }
            const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
                channelId: voiceChannel.id,
                guildId: interaction.guild.id,
                adapterCreator: interaction.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
            });

            // Cria uma resource de áudio
            const resource = createAudioResource(ytdl(videoID, { filter: 'audioonly' }));

            // Cria um player de áudio
            const player = createAudioPlayer();

            // Adiciona a resource ao player e faz o player tocar
            player.play(resource);
            connection.subscribe(player);

            // Envia uma mensagem de confirmação
            const embed = new EmbedBuilder ()
                .setColor('#0099ff')
                .setTitle('Música tocando!')
                .setDescription(`Tocando ${videoInfo.videoDetails.title}`)
                .setURL(`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${videoID}`)
                .setThumbnail(videoInfo.videoDetails.thumbnails[0].url);
            await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            await interaction.reply('Não foi possível reproduzir a música.');
        }
    },
};
```

I tried playing music on discord

Comment: Welcome to [so] please read the [tour] and [ask]